# Is there a way to decompress a teradata table?

Tags: teradata

I would like to decompress an already compressed Teradata table. I tried to give decompress /y "dbname.tbname" in ferret utility in Viewpoint but it threw an error. I am not sure if there is any keyword called decompress. Kindly help.

Comment: `HELP` wil show you that the command is named `UNCOMPRESS`

Comment: Also, maybe create table uncompressed_t as (select * from compressed_t) with data;